# Complex number in C

Tags: c

is it possible to do calculation like this in C?

```
A*exp(i*(b+c)) + D*exp(i*(e+f)),
```

where A,b,c,D,e,f are real numbers.

Comment: see section 7.3 in the [C99 Standard](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) or [C11 Standard](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf).

Comment: yes its possible , you can implement this in multiple ways in C and in even more ways if you do this in C++

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Section 7.3 in the [C99 Standard](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) (or [C11 Standard](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)) deals with complex numbers.

Example code

```
#include <complex.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    double A, b, c, D, e, f;
    complex double x;
    const complex double i = csqrt(-1);

    A = 1;
    b = 2;
    c = 3;
    D = 4;
    e = 5;
    f = 6;
    x = A * cexp(i * (b + c)) + D * cexp(i * (e + f));
    printf("value is %f + %fi\n", creal(x), cimag(x));
}
```

You can see the code running at ideone: http://ideone.com/d7xD7

The output is

```
value is 0.301365 + -4.958885i
```

Comment: I will only add that you do not need to define `const complex double i = csqrt(-1);` as the symbol `I` already represents the negative square root of -1 when you import `complex.h` (much as `M_PI` represent pi once you import `math.h`).

Answer (score 3):

[C99 introduces support for complex numbers](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Complex-Numbers.html).  Whether or not your compiler implements this feature I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you cannot represent real numbers in C. There are an infinite number of real numbers, but C has only finite precision in its calculations. That said, ISOC99 has a data type to do operations on Complex numbers within those bounds. http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Complex-Numbers.html

The C99 complex numbers are fairly limited- it really only provides a way to multiply by `i`. CMATH provides some excellent extensions with much more functionality than C99. http://www.optivec.com/cmfuncs/

Comment: It's not just that I'm bitter and twisted at losing rep to this answer, I think this answer is misleading. In general you **can** represent real numbers in C; like many programming languages C uses floating-point numbers to represent real numbers.  No, floating-point numbers are not real numbers, but they do represent them.  The widespread success of numerical computing offers support for the view that this representation is useful and successful.

Comment: @High Performance Mark you are correct, my pedantry in using "represent" is misleading, and I should have made a better effort to express the nuances in representing real numbers with finite precision arithmetic. I would defend my answer in providing additional reference to the cmath library, which provides a considerably more expressive API than C99.